# LambdaInvalidResponse nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following code running as an AWS Lambda function:

```js
const getDb = require('./db');
const Service = require('./service');


exports.main = async function (event, context) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const endpoint = event.path.split('/')[1].toLowerCase();

  const service = new Service(
    await getDb()
  );

  const result = await service[endpoint](); // result might be number or string, i.e. 123 or '123'
  
  return {
    isBase64Encoded: false,
    statusCode: 200,
    statusDescription: '200 OK',
    headers: {
      'Set-cookie': 'cookies',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: result,
  };
};
```

When I invoke it with aws-cli or the testing function in AWS console it works, but when I put it behind an ALB (application load balancer) it returns 502 Bad Gateway.

I have viewed the Lambda output CloudWatch logs. The endpoint is correctly invoked by the load balancer, but the load balancer access logs have the following entry:

```
2021-11-08T16:28:24.033000Z "forward" "-" "LambdaInvalidResponse" "-" "-" "-" "-"
```

Any ideas why I'm experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which of these things fixed it, but I did fix it:

- Wrap all properties in response object in quotes, i.e. `{ "body": result }` instead of `{ body: result }`
- serialized result, i.e. `{ "body": JSON.stringify({ result }) }` instead of `{ "body": result }`
- removed property `statusDescription` from response object